# nmap installation issue

Tags: centos, nmap

vanilla centos with latest updates, installed gcc, and after ./configure:....

```
Configuration complete.  Type make (or gmake on some *BSD machines) to compile.
[root@winxp nmap-5.51]# make
Makefile:375: makefile.dep: No such file or directory
g++ -MM -I./liblua -I./libdnet-stripped/include -I./libpcre  -I./libpcap -I./nbase -    I./nsock/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DNMAP_NAME=\"Nmap\" -DNMAP_URL=\"http://nmap.org\" -    DNMAP_PLATFORM=\"x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu\" -DNMAPDATADIR=\"/usr/local/share/nmap\" -  D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 main.cc nmap.cc targets.cc tcpip.cc nmap_error.cc utils.cc idle_scan.cc   osscan.cc osscan2.cc output.cc payload.cc scan_engine.cc timing.cc charpool.cc services.cc      protocols.cc nmap_rpc.cc portlist.cc NmapOps.cc TargetGroup.cc Target.cc   FingerPrintResults.cc service_scan.cc NmapOutputTable.cc MACLookup.cc nmap_tty.cc  nmap_dns.cc traceroute.cc portreasons.cc xml.cc nse_main.cc nse_utility.cc nse_nsock.cc  nse_dnet.cc nse_fs.cc nse_nmaplib.cc nse_debug.cc nse_pcrelib.cc nse_binlib.cc nse_bit.cc  >   makefile.dep
/bin/sh: g++: command not found
make: *** [makefile.dep] Error 127
[root@winxp nmap-5.51]# yum install g++ -y
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* addons: mirror.ash.fastserv.com
* base: centos.mirror.choopa.net
* extras: mirror.trouble-free.net
* updates: mirror.nexcess.net
Setting up Install Process
No package g++ available.
Nothing to do
[root@winxp nmap-5.51]#
```

Answer (score 0):

You should install g++.

```
yum install g++
```

The hint is  " No package g++ available "